# batch script working on 32 bit but not working on 64 bit

Tags: batch-file

I have following .bat file which is not working on win7 64 bit.I want it to run on win7 64 bit also.Please healp

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion


set x=^


rem for /f %%? in ('2^>nul ^( ^< output.md find /c /v "" ^)') do    set "$end=%%?"

rem echo.linefeeds[%$end%]


< output.md (

   for /l  %%i in (1, 1, 100) do set "b=" &set /p "b=" &(

      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
         (set /p y=!b!!x! <nul)
      endlocal
   )
) > out.md
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is the difference between what you get and what you expect?

Comment: This code is basically converting CRLF(dos format) into LF (UNIX format).It working totally fine under 32 bit win XP but under win7 64 bit  tabs in the beginning of each line is being disappeared.I dont want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

From windows Vista the `set /p` command removes spaces and tabs at the start of the output prompt. You can not use this method in windows 7

For a pure batch solution you can use

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure files 
    set "inputFile=input.txt"
    set "outputFile=output.txt"

    rem A temp file is needed
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.tmp"
    rem Retrieve a line feed into a variabla
    set LF=^



    rem Retrieve a SUB (0x1A) character into a variable
    copy nul "%tempFile%" /a >nul
    for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%tempFile%") do set "SUB=%%a"

    rem For each line inside input file
    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%inputFile%") do (
        rem Retrieve the line contents
        set "line=%%a"

        rem Output the line, a line feed a SUB and the CRLF (from echo) to a file
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >"%tempFile%" (echo(!line!!LF!!sub!)
        endlocal

        rem From the generated file, copy everything up to the SUB character
        rem The SUB and everything after it will be discarded
        >nul copy "%tempFile%" /a "%tempFile%2" /b

        rem Output the generated line
        type "%tempFile%2"

    )) > "%outputFile%"

    rem Remove temporary files used 
    del /q "%tempFile%*"
```

But a more efficient solution will be to use the native scripting engine available in the OS.

This is a hybrid cmd/jscript batch file (save with `.cmd` extension) to be used as

```
cr2lf.cmd < inputfile > outputFile
```

The code will just read standard input and for each input line output the same line followed with a line feed character

```dos
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    call :runInnerScript
    exit /b

:runInnerScript
    cscript //E:JScript "%~f0"
    goto :eof

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************

    while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream){
        WScript.StdOut.Write( WScript.StdIn.ReadLine() + '\n' );
    };
    // All done. Exit
    WScript.Quit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.But i used a dos2unix utility in my batch script that solve my job.Thanks anyway